# Match key and value from two different dictionaries and merge them

Tags: python-3.x

I have this two dictionaries:

```
    {'data': {'id': '001_101_001', 'name': 'chview', 'type': 'multiple', 'mapping': {}},
             {'id': '001_102_001', 'name': 'view', 'type': 'binary', 'mapping': {'abc':'exp'}}
```

And:

```
{'queries':{'view': 'text', 'chview': 'text1'}}
```

The desired output should be:

```
{'new_data' : {'001_101_001': { 'query': 'text1', 'type': 'multiple', 'mapping': {}}, 
               '001_102_001': { 'query1': 'text', 'type': 'binary', 'mapping': {'abc':'exp'}}
```

Because there are a lot of this dictionaries I need to match them by `'name'`, to have the coresponding `id` matched. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first dictionary has a problem, it is not hashable. It should be a list of dictionaries.

```
{"data" :[
    {'id': '001_101_001', 'name': 'chview', 'type': 'multiple', 'mapping': {}},
    {'id': '001_102_001', 'name': 'view', 'type': 'binary', 'mapping': {'abc':'exp'}}
]}
```

Complete code:

```
data = {"data" :[
    {'id': '001_101_001', 'name': 'chview', 'type': 'multiple', 'mapping': {}},
    {'id': '001_102_001', 'name': 'view', 'type': 'binary', 'mapping': {'abc':'exp'}}
]}

queries = {"queries" : {'view': 'text', 'chview': 'text1'}}

new_data = {}
for d in data["data"]:
    item = {d["id"] : {
        "query": queries["queries"][d["name"]],
        "type": d["type"],
        "mapping": d["mapping"]
    }}
    new_data.update(item)

print({"new_data": new_data})
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'new_data': {'001_101_001': {'query': 'text1', 'type': 'multiple', 'mapping': {}}, '001_102_001': {'query': 'text', 'type': 'binary', 'mapping': {'abc': 'exp'}}}}
```